# Html Agilitypack Getting Outer Items

Tags: asp.net, web-crawler, html-agility-pack

i need to get `<div class="month">May 2015</div>` and  `<div class="author">Alex Xander</div>` by `id="duyuru3483"`. How can i reach upper divs (XPATH code):

```
<div class="item">
<div class="dateBox">
   <div class="month">May 2015</div>
   <div class="day">07</div>
</div>
<div class="mainInfo">
<div class="title">
   <a href="#" class="text-justify" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#duyuru3483">
   2014-2015 Yılı Mezuniyet Töreni Hk. 
   </a>
   <div class="modal fade" id="duyuru3483" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
         <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header" style="background-color: #009E49;">
               <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
               <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">
                  <div class="duyuruBaslik">2014-2015 Yılı Mezuniyet Töreni Hk.</div>
               </h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
               <div class="duyuruMetni"> Mezuniyet törenine katılmak için yapılmasıgereken işlemler ve doldurulması gereken form ektedir. </div>
               <hr>
               <div class="author" > Ek :  <a style="color:##428bca" href="../files/19_mezuniyet.rar">indir</a>  </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Kapat</button>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="author">Alex Xander</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use `Ancestors`:

```
var modal = doc.GetElementbyId("duyuru3483");
var parent = modal.Ancestors()
                  .Single(e => e.Attributes["class"] !=null && 
                               e.Attributes["class"].Value == "item");
```

Another option is to use XPath:

```
var parent = doc.DocumentNode
                .SelectSingleNode("div[@class='item'][//div[@id='duyuru3483']]");
```

(you can algo get directly to `.dateBox` using:

```
div[@class='item'][//div[@id='duyuru3483']]/div[@class='dateBox']
```

And, of course, you can just use `ParentNode`, but that is less robust:

```
var parent = modal.ParentNode.ParentNode.ParentNode;
```

All of these get you to `.item` - it should be easy getting the data from there.